# Check if img src has correct path in TestCafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I perform a test with TestCafe and need to check if an img has the correct path. There are two img elements:

Case 1:

```
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-2" unselectable="on" id="dynamicID1">
     <img src="images/icons/bullet_wh.png">
     <img src="images/icons/bullet_re.png" id="dynamicID2">
</div>
```

Result of this case: there was an error before.

Case 2:

```
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-2" unselectable="on" id="dynamicID3">
     <img src="images/icons/bullet_gr.png">
     <img src="images/icons/bullet_wh.png" id="dynamicID4">
</div>
```

Result of this case: bullet_gr.png is on the site. Everthing is ok!

In my test I use `.expect(Selector('img[src="images/icons/bullet_gr.png"]'))` to check if the `bullet_gr.png` is visible on my site. Unfortunately the IDs are different on every visit (they get rendered when the user logs in and are unique for every visit). So I cannot use `.expect(Selector('#dynamicID4'))`.

As soon as I use the `.expect(Selector('img[src="images/icons/bullet_gr.png"]'))` line in my test it immediately finishes once the user is logged in with the test and I get the output that the test was successful.

What would be the solution to check if the bullet_gr.png is linked on the site?

Answer (score 3):

To check whether the element is on the page, use the [exists](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors.html#check-if-an-element-exists) property:

```
await t.expect(Selector('img[src="images/icons/bullet_gr.png"]')).ok()
```

or

```
const img = Selector('img').withAttribute('src', 'images/icons/bullet_gr.png');

await t.expect(img.exists).ok();
```